# SAS maximize a function of variables

Tags: sas

Given a set of variable `v(1) - v(k)`, a function `f` is defined as `f(v1,v2,...vk)`.

The target is to have a set of v(i) that maximize `f` given `v(1)+v(2)+....+v(k)=n`. All elements are restricted to non-negative integers.

**Note: I don't have `SAS/IML` or `SAS/OR`.**

If `k` is known, say `2`, then I can do sth like this.

```
data out;
    set in;
    maxf = 0;
    n1 = 0;
    n2 = 0;
    do i = 0 to n;
        do j = 0 to n;
            if i + j ne n then continue;
            _max = f(i,j);
            if _max > maxf then do;
                maxf = max(maxf,_max);
                n1 = i;
                n2 = j;
            end;
        end;
    end;
    drop i j;
run;
```

However, this solution has several issues.

1. Using loops seems to be very inefficient.
2. It doesn't know how may nested loops needed when k is unknown.

It's exactly the "Allocate n balls into k bins" problem where `k` is determined by # of columns in data `in` with specific prefix and `n` is determined by macro variable.

Function `f` is known, e.g `f(i,j) = 2*i+3*j`;

Is this possible to be done in data step?

Comment: Is f always a linear function of your variables? If so I would recommend using SAS to export the problem to another application like [lpsolve](https://sourceforge.net/projects/lpsolve/) rather than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @user667489 Unfortunately not....that's part of the reason I wonder if this problem is solvable....

Comment: [SCIP](http://scip.zib.de/) might be able to deal with this

Comment: Do you have SAS/STAT or SAS/ETS?

Comment: @dompazz not ets. But can you shed some light on how ets can do the trick?

Comment: Both SAS/STAT and SAS/ETS have procedures that allow you to specify a general likelihood function and them maximize that.  However, that will be continuous parameters.  Non-linear integer programs are hard...  Putting an example using a SAS/STAT procedure below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, general non-linear integer programs are hard to solve.  The method below will solve for continuous parameters.  You will have to take the output and find the nearest integer values that maximize your function.  However, the loop will now be much smaller and quicker to run.

First let's make a function.  This function has an extra parameter and is linear in that parameter.  Wrap your function inside something like this.

```
proc fcmp outlib=work.fns.fns;
function f(x1,x2,a);
    out = -10*(x1-5)*(x1-5) + -2*(x2-2)*(x2-2) + 2*(x1-5) + 3*(x2-2);
    return(out+a);
endsub;
run;quit;

options cmplib=work.fns;
```

We need to add the `a` parameter so that we can have a value that SAS can pass besides the actual parameters.  SAS will think it's solving the likelihood of `A`, based on `x1` and `x2`.

Generate a Data Set with an `A` value.

```
data temp;
a = 1;
run;
```

Now use `PROC NLMIXED` to maximize the likelihood of `A`.

```
ods output ParameterEstimates=Parameters;
ods select ParameterEstimates;

proc nlmixed data=temp;
parms x1=1 x2=1;
bounds x1>0, x2>0;

y = f(x1,x2,a);

model a ~ general(y);
run;

ods select default;
```

I get output of `x1=5.1` and `x2=2.75`.  You can then search "around" that to see where the maximum comes out.

Here's my attempt at a Data Step to search around the value:

```
%macro call_fn(fn,n,parr);
%local i;
&fn(&parr[1]
%do i=2 %to &n;
    , &parr[&i]
%end;
,0)
%mend;

%let n=2;
%let c=%sysevalf(2**&n);

data max;
set Parameters end=last;
array parms[&n] _temporary_;
array start[&n]  _temporary_;
array pmax[&n];
max = -9.99e256;

parms[_n_] = estimate;

if last then do;
    do i=1 to &n;
        start[i] = floor(parms[i]);
    end;

    do i=1 to &c;
        x = put(i,$binary2.);
        do j=1 to &n;
            parms[j] = input(substr(x,j,1),best.) + start[j];
        end;


        /*You need a macro to write this dynamically*/
        val = %call_fn(f,&n,parms);

        *put i= max= val=;
        if val > max then do;
            do j=1 to &n;
                pmax[j] = parms[j];
            end;
            max = val;
        end;
    end;
    output;
end;
```

Comment: Interesting solution. For the maximum likelihood part, I need to check the textbook for details, now can't remember the logic behind it..But I think once have the continuous solutions, finding the nearest integers should be easy. Still I have two questions. 1. In the first part, proc nlmixed doesn't guarantee the sum of x equals to n. Do you leave it for second part? 2. Don't understand how the substr part work..

Comment: I didn't see the constraint for sum(x) = n.  I will have to look at how to implement that.  The substr() part works because I am taking the C number of integers around the solution (2^n).  I count up to C, converting the number to a binary string -- ie 2 = 10.  I then grab the jth value in that string with the substr() function and add it to the starting value.  That gives me an easy way to make sure I add all combinations of 0 and 1 to the starting values.

Comment: And don't worry about the likelihood part.  It's just maximizing a function.

Comment: NLMIXED does not have a constraint such that I can force sum(x)=n.  PROC MODEL in SAS/ETS would allow this.

Comment: I think sum(x) <= n will not be guaranteed in the solution. Need to add sum(x)<=n in the bounds statement. However, such constraint could be violated in the loop keep adding 0s and 1s